# Create a session using JavaServlets without creating a Cookies

Tags: java, session, servlets, server, server-side

## How to create a session without creating the cookie with JavaServlets?

The `request.getSession()` method allows to create a session and creates a cookie with the JSESSIONID attribute.

Now if we want to handle the situation in which cookies are disabled we can use the command `response.encodeURL("path")` which adds the session ID to the url only if it's necessary.

So:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String encodedURL=response.encodeURL("path")
```

This seems to cover all the possibilities but i have a particular need: i want to offer to the user the possibility to **not allow any cookies even if they are enabled in the browser**. In this if cookies are disabled everything works fine because the encodeURL manages it. But if the **cookies are enabled** i can't find i cannot use  the previous solution because the first instruction **creates the session and consequently the Cookie**.

Is there a way to ***create a session without setting immediately the cookie***?

There could be a solution with ServletContext.setSessionTrackingModes() but i didn't quite found the answer.

Comment: Does `getSession(false)` work?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the false attribute is used to avoid creating a session if there isn't one. So no it's not helpfull

Comment: Which servlet container?  The container should (hopefully) support this configuration.  Also, if URL session encoding is used, then be aware of potential security issues, e.g., users sharing URLs, and also stale bookmarks.

Comment: I am using Tomcat, since is a University project i am not worried about security issues right know.

Comment: What you posted is wrong.   setSessionTrackingModes is a method of the ServletContext interface, NOT HttpServletRequest.

Comment: You are right that the correct interface is ServletContext

Answer (score 0):

I have created a work-around solution that creates the session and then deletes the cookies created by it. In this way nothing is left in the user browser after the creation of the session.

**First action**: create session and get the origin url of the request:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String origin = request.getHeader("referer");
```

**Second action**: use encodeURL to ensure that the session works even if the cookies are disabled from the browser:

```
String encodedURL = origin;
encodedURL = response.encodeURL(origin);
```

**Third action**: check if the URL rewriting has been done, in case is not (*meaning that cookies are enabled*) manually rewrite it:

```
 if(Objects.equals(encodedURL, origin)){
            String JSESSIONID=session.getId();
            encodedURL =encodedURL +"JSESSIONID="+JSESSIONID;
```

**Fourth action**: delete cookies:

```
Cookie [] cookies= request.getCookies();
            for(Cookie i:cookies){
                i.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(i);
            }
```

**FIfth action**: Redirect using the encodedURL:

```
response.sendRedirect(encodedURL);
```

This solution is partial because the session creation still produce a cookie but the fourth action deletes it, "fixing" the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have to first ask the user if he wants to use cookies this time or not, save the answer in a boolean and then use if-else to create a session either with or without cookies

Comment: The problem is, if the cookies are enabled in the browser, how do you create a session avoiding the default creation of the cookie?